# Continuous integration with AWS and Django

Tags: django, continuous-integration

I'm looking at setting up a continuous integration solution for a Django framework project hosted in AWS.  Their are client and server tests.  The client tests will fire up a headless browser, but it would also be good if it could fire up real browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

Repo hosted on BitBucket.  What would be great is if code is committed to a branch, then the CI setup will pull the changes and run the tests in an environment that closely matches production.

Can you help me set up the best possible stack given the above constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I think Fabric would be suitable for this. Fabric allows you to run code on your local machine and the server. Once you learn the basics of Fabric, you will see that you can run a command like 'fab deploy' and Fabric will commit your changes to a branch, then pull the changes onto the server.

You could have steps in between to launch a new server, prepare the environment, then run tests against the code. I have been using Fabric to simplify some deployments and have found it a great experience. Because of the flexibility fabric gives you, you can pretty much deploy however you want, whether it's onto a test server, QA, live etc...